# duplicate webpack (2.2.0) chunks with vue-components

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-2

When I build my bundle (dev works fine) I find that two chunks (names starting with 0 and 1; 1.08Mb and 1.07Mb respectively) are almost completely similar. Content of chunk 1 is covered completely by content of chunk 0 and chunk 0 is slightly larger containing an extra child vue component. To me it seems like all imports of a child.vue component are again included when the child.vue component is imported into a parent.vue component. I thought webpack would weed this out... but apparently not.

The parent.vue component:

```
<script type='text/babel'>
import Child from './Child.vue'

export default {
  name: 'parent',
  components: {Child}
}

</script>
```

relevant part of child.vue component:

```
<script type='text/babel'>
import turf from 'turf'
import {resize} from '@most/dom-event' 

[[etc]]
```

in router.js:

```
  routes: [
    { path: '/parent', component: load('parent') },
    { path: '/', component: load('Index') }, // Default
    { path: '*', component: load('Error404') } // Not found
  ]
})
```

I also would expect the turf and all other npm packages from node_modules to go into a separate vendor chunk, but they are in both chunk 0 and 1: (i.e. no vendor chunks):

```
Hash: 1b94a25680bff29f4960
Version: webpack 2.2.0
Time: 44975ms
                                   Asset       Size      Chunks                    Chunk Names
            js/5.ceea6d62238ac33ab65a.js  987 bytes        5, 8  [emitted]         
fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.012cf6a.woff    57.6 kB              [emitted]         
            js/1.00c968884dd42ca9abe7.js    1.07 MB        1, 8  [emitted]  [big]  
            js/2.a15df363f7a95520359b.js    6.28 kB  2, 3, 5, 8  [emitted]         
            js/3.09b86cd9939dea1b32d0.js    2.53 kB        3, 8  [emitted]         
            js/4.1de965c7ddc632ca7966.js    1.95 kB        4, 8  [emitted]         
            js/0.5c94c88f8cc301c30326.js    1.08 MB     0, 1, 8  [emitted]  [big]  
                            js/vendor.js     562 kB        6, 8  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
                               js/app.js    9.68 kB        7, 8  [emitted]         app
                          js/manifest.js    1.58 kB           8  [emitted]         manifest
app.8a73cdb0886334e9bc2ff358859b1203.css     246 kB        7, 8  [emitted]         app
                              index.html  616 bytes              [emitted]         

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What am I doing wrong?:

1. why do I have duplicate code in my chunks?
2. why are node_module libraries not in the vendor chunk?

Answer (score 0):

when I get rid of the load function in my routes it works as expected (and vendor chunk is also as expected) and I get:

```
Hash: 44e71b7f99a8c23f744a
Version: webpack 2.2.0
Time: 37300ms
                                   Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.012cf6a.woff    57.6 kB          [emitted]         
                            js/vendor.js    1.59 MB    0, 2  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
                               js/app.js    41.6 kB    1, 2  [emitted]         app
                          js/manifest.js    1.43 kB       2  [emitted]         manifest
app.1b4a3bd6bcac26b9462e4d297ad634b4.css     270 kB    1, 2  [emitted]  [big]  app
                              index.html  616 bytes          [emitted]         

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I got the load function from [here](https://github.com/quasarframework/app-template-default/blob/master/template/src/router.js).

And also find this way of dealing with the routes in other repos, so probably it serves a purpose. I will ask overthere.